# Could you look at this javascipt canvas?

Tags: javascript

I am reading something at the library and the link is dead so I wanted to retry making a java canvas... well here

```js
indow.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded() {
  canvasApp();
}

function canvasApp() {
  var theCanvas = document.getElementById('my_first_canvas');
  var my_canvas = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
  my_canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, 200, 225)
  // to start, draw a border around the canvas
  //draw face
  my_canvas.beginPath();
  my_canvas.arc(100, 100, 75, (Math.PI / 180) * 0, (Math.PI / 180) * 360, false);
  // circle dimensions
  my_canvas.strokeStyle = "black"; // circle outline is black
  my_canvas.lineWidth = 3; // outline is three pixels wide
  my_canvas.fillStyle = "yellow"; // fill circle with yellow
  my_canvas.stroke(); // draw circle 
  my_canvas.fill();
  my_canvas.closePath();
  // now , draw left eye
  my_canvas.fillStyle = "black";
  my_canvas.beginPath();
  my_canvas.arc(65, 70, 10, (Math.PI / 180) * 0, (Math.PI / 180) * 360, false);
  // circle dimstions 
  my_canvas.stroke(); // draw circle
  my_canvas.fill(); //fill in circel 
  my_canvas.closePath();

  // now the right eyes

  my_canvas.beginPath();
  my_canvas.arc(135, 70, 10, (Math.PI / 180) * 0, (Math.PI / 180) * 360, false);
  // circle dimstions 
  my_canvas.stroke(); // draw circle
  my_canvas.fill(); //fill in circel 
  my_canvas.closePath();

  // draw smile 
  my_canvas.lineWidth = 6;
  my_canvas.beginPath();
  my_canvas.arc(99, 120, 35, (Math.PI / 180) * 0, (Math.PI / 180) * -180, false);

  // semicircle dimensions
  my_canvas.stroke();
  my_canvas.closePath();

  // Smiley speaks!
  my_canvas.fillStyle = "black";
  my_canvas.font = '5000px _sans';
  my_canvas.fillText("Hello Canvas!", 45, 200);
}
```

```html
    <canvas width="10000" heigth="55500" id="my_first_canvas">
      Your browsers does not support HTML5 canvas. Try using Chrome,Firefox,Safari or MS Edge.
      </canvas>
```

but ruing it only show all the way up the smile did I miss spell something... I been look at this page for about 2 hours now i had done this over a week ago and just read that I massing the html element go being fg

Comment: Fix the typo on line one `indow` so it runs, then perhaps explain your problem a little more since it is not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better practice

```
  var theCanvas = document.getElementById('my_first_canvas');
  theCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  theCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: Where do I put this? Mine knowledge is very limited since I had just started.

Comment: @Markdmatzke you put this at the beginning of CanvasApp function

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, you spelled height wrong. It worked for me after that.

```
<canvas width="10000" height="5600" id="my_first_canvas">
      Your browsers does not support HTML5 canvas. Try using Chrome,Firefox,Safari or MS Edge.
</canvas>
```